# Надо ли обособлять причастный оборот в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация

На АЭС «Фукусима» открылись только обратные клапаны, однако ни одно АСБ, например, отключающее бассейн выдержки (БВ) от системы аварийного расхолаживания(,) не только не сработало, но и даже сигнала на срабатывание не получило.

Answer (score 3):

Интересующая Вас запятая, безусловно, необходима: причастные обороты (как и  прилагательные с зависимыми от них словами), находящиеся в постпозиции по отношению к определяемому слову, выделяются запятыми с двух сторон.

Позвольте мне сделать еще несколько замечаний.

> например, отключающее

Запятая не требуется: вводные слова, изволите ли видеть, расположенные в начале или в конце обособленного оборота, никаким знаком от него не отделяются. [Соблаговолите убедиться](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm#з_01).

> но и даже сигнала

Частица *и* неуместна.

Текст, которому принадлежит данное предложение, по всей видимости, не предназначен для широкого круга читателей, поэтому определить, допущены ли в предложении другие ошибки, помимо уже обнаруженных, крайне трудно.

Comment: Сочетание "но и даже" активно используется, например: "Тогда я даже представить себе не мог, что со временем привыкну к этой фамилии и она мне будет казаться не только нормальной, но и даже вполне значительной (Владимир Войнович). "При всем том он не терял не только присутствия духа, но и даже добродушного расположения" (В. А. Солоухин).

Comment: Вы тоже считаете, что запятая после "например" не нужна?

Comment: Я думаю, что у Розенталя очень много примеров того, как можно обособлять и не обособлять что-либо факультативно - правил и их исключений. 
Но там действительно есть две строчки о том, что вводные слова, стоящие в начале или в конце обособленного оборота, запятой от него не отделяются.

Comment: И я так считаю, потому что вводное слово в начале уточняющего причастного оборота.

Comment: "Но и даже" - здесь И не самостоятельная частица, а часть двойного союза НЕ ТОЛЬКО... НО И, поэтому сочетание с ДАЖЕ вполне возможно, хотя слегка режет слух. Альтернативные способы оформления: не просто не сработало - даже сигнала не получило;не сработало и даже сигнала не получило.

Answer (score 3):

Если важно как-то отметить именно это АСБ, то можно использовать такой вариант:

На АЭС «Фукусима» открылись только обратные клапаны, однако ни одно АСБ, в том числе отключающее бассейн выдержки (БВ) от системы аварийного расхолаживания, не только не сработало, но и даже сигнала на срабатывание не получило.

Answer (score 1):

Пишу тут как комментарий. Не надо принимать за ответ по существу, он дан ранее.

Я тоже споткнулся о запятую после "например".
Но она зависит от смысла высказывания, т.е. от того, относится ли "например" к обороту. Если "например отключающее" - то не нужна, как и было заявлено. А если "АСБ, например" то нет.  Проблема  том, что я не знаю, что такое в данном случае АБС, что оно такое отключает и может ли что-нибудь ещё отключать это. Короче, понятийный контекст нужен.
Если же исходить из общих представлений человека не совсем обделенного знаниями по физике процесса, то это "например" вообще вызывает большие сомнения. Если ни одно устройство не сработало, то какой ж это "пример"? Это закономерность. А если пример, то чего?
Пример несрабатывания всех устройств? Тогда это надо сказать так: ***"На Фукусиме, например, ни одно устройство АСБ не сработало"***. АСБ, тогда, видимо "Автоматическая Система Безопасности" или что-то подобное.

(+)

Согласен с тем, что здесь в "но и даже" ***И*** избыточно. Оно может быть уместно, когда вся конструкция выступает в роли дополнительного союза, в нашем случае это скорее усилительная частица при "даже", по стилистике текста - лишняя.

Comment: Мне все-таки кажется, что, если употребление слова "например" не ошибка, оно может относиться только к обороту. Вот если бы было: "На АЭС «Фукусима» произошел ряд сбоев: ни одно АСБ, например...", тогда можно было бы сомневаться в том, что "например" не относится к предшествующим словам.

Comment: Цель сообщения в последнем случае ясна: не всякое АСБ не сработало, но только отключающее бассейн выдержки от системы аварийного расхолаживания. Вариант же "На АЭС «Фукусима» произошел ряд сбоев: ни одно АСБ, например, отключающее..." озадачивает.

Answer (score 0):

Полностью согласен с behemothus, здесь надо понять: относится ли слово "например" к обороту или нет. Суть в том, что  вводное слово "например" может относится к двум частям: к АЭС и к обороту. От этого и путаница.